# How can I use Process Monitor to detect register changes made by GPEdit modifications?

Tags: windows, gpedit, process-monitor

It is supposed that [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) can capture the **registry changes** made by any program. This [thread](https://superuser.com/a/317907/268923) explains it fine (thanks you, James T).

But it seems things are not so easy when talking about **Group Policies Editor** (`gpedit.msc`), because I am getting more than 738 register events when trying to change just one entry:

```
User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Code signing for drivers
```

[image: Lots of captured data]

How can I **isolate** the specific registry change for my GPEdit change performed?

New data:

As suggested by Frank Thomas (thanks), there was only one `RegSetValue` entry, named `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{7C9BF3F4-1B9E-476F-871D-D20B09E6DA5A}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing\BehaviorOnFailedVerify`.
This `BehaviorOnFailedVerify` key was what I was changing, but such key has been changed in **multiple places** at the register:

- At `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{7C9BF3F4-1B9E-476F-871D-D20B09E6DA5A}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing` as stated.
- At `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing`.
- At `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1389804526-12218611-1726603683-1004\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{7C9BF3F4-1B9E-476F-871D-D20B09E6DA5A}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing`.
- At `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1389804526-12218611-1726603683-1004\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing`.

This is: **four changes**, and only one of them  has been detected by Process Monitor.
Is this correct? Why?
If pretending to perform the same change via the `reg` command (without using `gpedit.msc`, which one should I change? All the four?

**Note**: I did not explain, as long as I did not think it was necessary, but my original idea was to be capable to change the key `BehaviorOnFailedVerify` via **remote shell**, like SSH or telnet).
**Note-2**: For those wondering what does this change: it **disables driver signature verification request** so nothing prompts no the screen to the GUI user when installing some unsigned drivers like TAP-driver (network) for OpenVPN unattended installation.

Comment: Well, every entry you show except the one you have highlighted, is a RegQueryKey, RegEnumKey, RegOpenKey, or RegCloseKey event, so thats the process reading the registery, whereas your RegSetValue is the event noting that the registery has been written to. you can filter on that event, or if you have the full path of the key, filter on the Path.

Comment: Indeed, @FrankThomas . But I am not still sure that the procedure is working. Updated post; please read.

Comment: try using a `Contains` query (rather than an `is`) on the Path filter, so you are only matching against `BehaviorOnFailedVerify` or `Windows NT\Driver Signing`.

Comment: Just to point something out on this, despite the age of the question, it is actually only changing in two locations as far as I can tell. HKCU is contained as a sub-key within HKU, so if you change something in HKCU it will, of course, also change in HKU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) instead. Attach it to the `MMC.exe` that runs gpedit, and click on the green arrow to start logging. If you change the entries, the tool generates a .reg file that you can save and use later again.

Comment: Thanks you, magicandre1981. This one seems the correct program to monitor registry changes. But it still have the same problem related on the «changed in multiple places at the register» part of the original question: RegFromApp only detects one of the four changes to the register. Maybe there is no exact correspondence between register and GPEdit?

Comment: what do you mean with "changed in multiple places at the register"?

Comment: The four bullet points are an example of the four changes that I discovered (by searching in RegEdit). As stated, only one was detected by Process Monitor and RegFromApp.

Comment: which key does the tool detect? the value under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies** should be enough.

Comment: The tool detect only the first of the four values (see the `New data` part of the question), this is: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{7C9BF3F4-1B9E-476F-871D-D20B09E6DA5A}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing` .

Comment: When you say "should be enough", do you mean that changing the value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies` will create some sort of cascade change on the other three? Could you explain why should that happen?

Comment: no, the others look to be status values, so that gpedit knows what was changed by itself and what by other tools.